# Any twitteR type package for Facebook in R Programming?

Tags: facebook, r

Are there any packages in R for Facebook that are similar to twitteR?  I would like to analyze Facebook data just like the twitteR package does for Twitter.

My objective is to analyze how the facebookers talking about a certain keyword. Alike analysis had been done for Twitter with twitteR package. For example: [Twitter Listening Robot](http://www.cloudstat.org/index.php?do=/kafechew/blog/twitter-listening-apps/). This analysis can tell us who is tweeting, retweeting, who is the top users, when they are tweeting, who is tweeting whom, wordcloud and so.

I would like to replicate the same for Facebook. I just started researching about this and found that lack of public Facebook analysis using R.

Some useful resources for this topic I found:

1. [Facebook Mining](https://gist.github.com/1634662)
2. [Mining Facebook Data: Most "Liked" Status and Friendship Network](http://applyr.blogspot.com/2012/01/mining-facebook-data-most-liked-status.html?spref=tw)

Updated 23 June:

Since lack of information about the public facebook graph analysis, I would like to start the ball rolling, here are some source code or information might be useful. Join me if you're interested.

- [Facebook Graph: Scrapping Social Info with R](http://www.cloudstat.org/index.php?do=/kafechew/blog/facebook-graph-scrapping-social-info-with-r/) is the Facebook Graph (#API) parameter summary.
- [Most LIKES facebook post for keyword UMNO 3](http://www.cloudstat.org/index.php?do=/kafechew/blog/most-likes-facebook-post-for-keyword-umno-3/) is a sample R script with Facebook Graph application.

Comment: Have you done a search for `[r] facebook` in StackOverflow? There seem to be a number of almost identical questions already.

Comment: Yes. I did. The only most related is the facebook text mining. So, I have to open this thread. Feel free to suggest if you had better solutions, with StackOverFlow or outside. Thanks.

Comment: People will be more inclined to help if you state in your question what you have already tried / found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, You can use Rfacebook package. You can access to almost everything in your account (or even change your fb status).

More information here:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rfacebook/
https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook

Step-by-step tutorial on getting started with RFacebook is here:
http://thinktostart.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/analyzing-facebook-with-r/

And some example of using it:
http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/11/how-to-analyze-you-facebook-friends-network-with-r.html

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly the same as what twitteR does. But you may have a look at posts by David Smith (Revolutions Analytics).

1. Analysis of Facebook status updates http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2010/12/analysis-of-facebook-status-updates.html
2. Facebook-class social network analysis with R and Hadoop http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/05/facebook-class-social-network-analysis-with-r-and-hadoop.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is [one more blogpost](http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?post/2012/01/15/Crawling-facebook-with-R) on this topic.